# GenABEL on R4.2.2 Windows

Tags: r, archive, r-package, gwas

I´m looking for a way to use GenABEL on R4.2.2 with Rstudio-2022.07.2-576.
GenABEL is only accessible through the R archive with latest version from 2017 or github GenABEL-Project /
GenABEL(https://github.com/GenABEL-Project/GenABEL).

Was first trying to use devtools:

```r
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("GenABEL-Project/GenABEL")

#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In utils::untar(tarfile, ...) :
#>   ‘tar.exe -xf "C:\Users\Anne\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQnQiaa\file14785f1e59c1.tar.gz" -C "C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQnQiaa/remotes1478e0b3485"’ returned error code 1
#> 2: In i.p(...) :
#>   Installation des Pakets ‘C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQnQiaa/file147853b04d76/GenABEL_1.8-0.tar.gz’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
```

after that I was trying to use the description of:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/using-r-installing-genabel-and-repeatabel/
But also no chance.

First I install the package curl. With:
curl -O https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/GenABEL/GenABEL_1.8-0.tar.gz
there was an

> Error: unexpected symbol in "curl -O https". I also tried -0, -o and -O. No chance.

Some other google research did not have any usable results.
Hopefully somebody can help me.
Best regards!